# Value of cell 2 should depend on value of cell 1 in an Interactive Grid. Why does it only work in some cases?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I have an `Interactive Grid` that has Year and Months. There is a table of months to allow per chosen year.
I am implementing this in the IG so that the user doesn´t choose an invalid month.
This is working in existing records but it's not working on new records.
When I add a new line I can choose the year I want but the month will be empty. If however i click in another line and go back the list of months will be correct.

---

1. After adding new line and choosing the year:

[image]

---

2. Clicking outside:

[image]

---

3. Going back to the line to be inserted:

[image]

I'm making sure the month has the year as `Cascading LOV Parent Column(s)` and `Items to Submit`.
I have also tried to add a default year as a `default` in the column settings and also with a DA with JS and made sure it was formatted as a number (I'm not sure this part is important but I tried anyway)

Comment: Can you share screenshot of the cascading lov definition ?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem in the meanwhile. Setting the optimize refresh to 'No' solved the issue.